# How to create an auxiliary page with sub url?

Tags: templating, entries, field, slug

I have a section where each item has its own URL e.g:
news/{slug}

The Entry Template for this section is:
news/news_detail

For each post I would like to have a link to a unique page which is populated with information from the fields from the parent post/group, e.g news.

The slug would look something like:
news/{slug}/extra

The Entry Template for the news_detail page has a rich text field:
additional

To make this more complicated, the link to this page will be visible only if the "additional" field is populated with data.
And finally each "extra" page should have a link back to the originating post.

I had considered using a simple JavaScript toggle, but having urls for the content is more important in this instance, so not an option.

Thank you for any pointers as I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want 3 templates — I'll call them 'news/index.html', 'news/_entry.html', and 'news/_extra.html'. (fyi... using an underscore before the template name is good practice as it prevents the template from being loaded directly; which would likely throw an error because no entry would be defined.)

You'll then want to create a custom route to the 'extra' page in settings, using the 'slug' token for one of the segments.

- If your url looks like this: news/slug/extra (where 'slug' is the slug token)
- Load this template: news/_extra.html

In the '_entry.html' template, you'll want to check your 'additional' field and create a link to your '/extra' page. Note: 'entry.url' should already include the 'news/slug' portion of the uri — we'll just be adding the '/extra' segment.

```
{% if entry.additional %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url ~ '/extra' }}">extra page</a>
{% endif %}
```

In the '_extra.html' template, there should now be a 'slug' variable available to your entry.

```
{% set newsEntry = craft.entry.section('news').slug(slug) %}
{% set newsIndex = craft.entry.section('pages').slug('news') %}
{{ newsIndex.title }} — {{ newsEntry.title }}
```

Note: I don't know in what section your 'news' index page is. I just picked something at random — you'll need to change that to match your structure.

Comment: To clarify your final note, the news index page in this example would belong to news. In relation to the actual template folder structure what I have is as follows: root = news.html then a folder called News with two templates inside called news_entry.html and news_extra.html – So in your example you use news/index.html, when it should be news.html – Did this match your understanding? Thank you for your answer and for pointing me in the right direction on this.

Comment: Yes. You can change the templates/paths to anything you want. I just used those as an example. I would still recommend placing an underscore in front of any templates that rely on an entry being defined however (i.e. '_news_entry.html' and '_news_extra.html').

Comment: I have renamed the last segment of Craft code as follows: {% set newsEntry = craft.entry.section('news').slug(slug) %}
{% set newsIndex = craft.entry.section('news').slug('news') %}
{{ newsIndex.title }} — {{ newsEntry.title }} - I am not sure where exactly to put this, and know that it is why {{ entry.newsExtra }} isn't loading in any information on the _extra.html page. The url which the user clicks on to see the extra page reads _extra.html - does this have to be the case, can it be made prettier without underscores while also taking your advice at the template side?

Comment: The {{ newIndex.title}} and {{ newsEntry.title}} are just an example to show you that you can access those entries as needed from your '_extras.html' template. Change to whatever you need. As far as the uri is concerned—you shouldn't have '_extra' in the uri, only in the route template definition. The uri should be 'news/{slug}/extra' where slug is the title of your news entry.